# Prediction on new data with GLMNET and CARET - The number of variables in newx must be X

Tags: r, r-caret, predict, glmnet

I have a dataset with which I am doing k-folds cross-validation with.

In each fold, I have split the data into a train and test dataset.

For the training on the dataset X, I run the following code:

```
cv_glmnet <- caret::train(x = as.data.frame(X[curtrainfoldi, ]), y = y[curtrainfoldi, ],
                       method = "glmnet",
                       preProcess = NULL,
                       trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
                       tuneLength = 10)
```

I check the class of 'cv_glmnet', and 'train' is returned.

I then want to use this model to predict values in the test dataset, which is a matrix that has the same number of variables (columns)

```
# predicting on test data 
yhat <- predict.train(cv_glmnet, newdata = X[curtestfoldi, ])
```

However, I keep running into the following error:

```
Error in predict.glmnet(modelFit, newdata, s = modelFit$lambdaOpt, type = "response") : 
  The number of variables in newx must be 210
```

I noticed in the caret.predict documentation, it states the following:

> newdata    an optional set of data to predict on. If NULL, then the
> original training data are used but, if the train model used a recipe,
> an error will occur.

I am confused as to why am I running into this error. Is it related to how I am defining newdata? My data has the right number of variables/columns (same as the train dataset), so I have no idea what is causing the error.

Comment: something wrong with your dataframe most likely. check `dim(as.data.frame(X[curtrainfoldi, ]))` and `dim(X[curtrainfoldi, ])`

Comment: @StupidWolf, thank you for the response. Both commands return the exact say number of columns, which should be the case from my understanding. Any other ideas as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: yes it should... so i cannot reproduce your error..

Comment: converting X[curtrainfoldi, ] to a data.frame as well seemed to have solved the issue. I am not sure exactly why that does it, since it still has the same number of columns, but all seems to be working now.

Comment: it's the column names.. i guess you either have no columns in the matrix, or you have column names that are changed by as.data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because your column names changes when you pass `as.data.frame(X)`. If your matrix doesn't have column names, it creates column names and the model expects these when it tries to predict. If it has column names, then some of them could be changed :

```
library(caret)
library(tibble)

X =  matrix(runif(50*20),ncol=20)
y = rnorm(50)

cv_glmnet <- caret::train(x = as.data.frame(X), y = y,
                       method = "glmnet",
                       preProcess = NULL,
                       trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
                       tuneLength = 10)

yhat <- predict.train(cv_glmnet, newdata = X) 

Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
Error in predict.glmnet(modelFit, newdata, s = modelFit$lambdaOpt) : 
  The number of variables in newx must be 20
```

If you have column names, it works

```
colnames(X) = paste0("column",1:ncol(X))
cv_glmnet <- caret::train(x = as.data.frame(X), y = y,
                       method = "glmnet",
                       preProcess = NULL,
                       trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
                       tuneLength = 10)

yhat <- predict.train(cv_glmnet, newdata = X)
```